# Why Math.max(...[]) is equal to -Infinity in ES2015?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

`Math.max([])` would be `0`

And `[..[]]` is `[]`

But why `Math.max(...[])` is equal to `-Infinity` in ES2015?

Comment: Not that I need to know the answer, but I would also like to know.

Comment: You're passing no arguments at all; `-Infinity` is where `Math.max()` starts from, so with no arguments that's what you get as an answer.

Comment: From [the MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max): *If no arguments are given, the result is `-Infinity.`*

Comment: Note that `Math.max([])` is `0` because `Number([])` is `0`.

Comment: If applicable (i.e. you want '0' as your default), try `Math.max(0, ...[])`

Comment: As a sidenote, you might want to check infinity with `Number.isFinite`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What happens with `Math.max([])` is that `[]` is first converted to a string and then to a number. It is not actually considered an array of arguments.

With `Math.max(...[])` the array is considered a collection of arguments through the spread operator. Since the array is empty, this is the same as calling without arguments.
Which according to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) produces -Infinity

> If no arguments are given, the result is -Infinity.

---

Some examples to show the difference in calls with arrays:

```js
console.log(+[]); //0    [] -> '' -> 0
console.log(+[3]); //3    [] -> '3' -> 3
console.log(+[3,4]); //Nan 
console.log(...[3]); //3
console.log(...[3,4]); //3 4 (the array is used as arguments)
console.log(Math.max([])); //0  [] is converted to 0
console.log(Math.max()); // -infinity:  default without arguments
console.log(Math.max(...[])); // -infinity
console.log(Math.max([3,4])); //Nan
console.log(Math.max(...[3,4])); //4
```

Answer (score 4):

If you see the [internal implementation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-math.max) documentation, you can tell why `Math.max` is returning -Infinity when there is no argument passed.

> If no arguments are given, the result is -∞.

So when you spread an empty array in a function call, it is like calling the function without an argument.

Comment: But the result is **negative** infinity, not positive.

Comment: @Pointy Hmm.. Interesting, even if i call `Math.max()`, It is giving me -`Infinity`. I think there must be typo there in the documentation. Let me look out for recent doc.

Comment: In the very document you linked, it clearly says `-∞`. Positive infinity is what's returned from `Math.min()` when you pass no arguments.

Comment: @Pointy Uff.. Sorry man.. I was just confused. I linked a doc related to min. Corrected and updated the answer. Thanks for pointing though pointy ;)

Answer (score 4):

FTR the way to get around this is to use a MIN value with the spread operator. Like:

```
Math.max(MIN_VALUE, ...arr)
Math.max(0, ...[]) --> 0
Math.max(0, ...[1]) --> 1
Math.max(0, ...[23,1]) --> 23
```

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the babel output for `Math.max(...[])`, you end up with `Math.max.apply(Math, [])`. If you log that in ES5, you see that for some reason it gives you `-Infinity`, because it's the same as calling it without an argument.

And indeed, `Math.max()` gives `-Infinity`

If you need a reminder: `fn.apply( yourThis, [ a, b, c ] )` is the same as `fn( a, b, c )`

Answer (score 2):

Because `Math.max(...[])` is not `Math.max([...[]])`. In the first case, what You really call is `Math.max()`, which is `-Infinity`. See the spread operator in function call - https://developer.mozilla.org/cs/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Answer (score 1):

When finding out what the biggest number is, where do you start? The answer is the lowest number, -Infinity

```
function max (array) {
    var highest = -Infinity;

    foreach(elem in array) if (elem > highest) highest= elem;

    return highest;
}
```

Not accurate code but you get the gist, credit to my friend since the internet let me down once again.