# Run function after all tiles have been processed

Tags: javascript, openlayers

How do I get a function to run after [forEachTileCoord](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_tilegrid_TileGrid-TileGrid.html) have been processing all tiles?

I have been writting a script to recolor a WMTS-layer based on the currently displayed tiles. The script is going through all the tiles to figure out what their maximum values are and then color the tiles based the biggest value in any of the displayed tiles. The coloring part works fine, but it doesn't wait for all of the tiles to be processed.

In my code attached at the bottom the last half shouldn't trigger before all tiles have been processed. I presume that I would need to use [Promises](https://javascript.info/promise-basics). Issue is I don't know how to define when the forEachTileCoord is finished.

```
  map.on("moveend", function() {
  var tileUrlFunction = tileSource.getTileUrlFunction()
  var maxValues = [];
  var loadExtent = map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize());
  //Checks which tiles that currently are being displayed
  tileSource.getTileGrid().forEachTileCoord(loadExtent, mapZoom, function(tileCoord) {

    //Gets the name of each currently displayed tile
    tileName = tileUrlFunction(tileCoord, ol.proj.get('EPSG:4326'))
    asyncCall()

    async function asyncCall() {
    tileMaxValue = await calculateMaxValue(tileName);
    maxValues.push(tileMaxValue)
    }

    })


//This next part triggers too early - returns -Infinity
  currentMax = Math.max(...maxValues)
  if (Number.isInteger(currentMax)) {
//This is the function for recoloring the map
    olgt_map.redraw(olgt_map, currentMax, colorScale);
  }  
  }
```

The redraw function is changing the legend values and the coloring distribution of the layer as illustrated [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftLI6.png). The two screenshots are two different areas of the same map. Legend and coloring are being adjusted to the max value currently being shown.

```
olGeoTiff.prototype.redraw = function(map, currentMax, legendValues) {

    map.plotOptions.domain = [0, currentMax];

  this.layer.getSource().refresh();
  updateLegend(legendValues, currentMax);
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you redraw function is doing, but the layer's `postrender` event might be the suitable, or perhaps he map's `rendercomplete` event.

Comment: Replacing `moveend` with `rendercomplete` should work, but check that the `currentMax` value has changed before redrawing to avoid an endless cycle

Comment: currentMax is returning "-Infinity", which is due to the [array being empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42719786/why-math-max-is-equal-to-infinity-in-es2015). This seem also to have been the case, when I had `moveend` as my trigger

Comment: Is it zero length or full or undefined?  It would be better to use the API method `.getTileGrid()` instead of `.tileGrid`. If `calculateMaxValue` is loading from a URL it will be asynchronous.

Comment: It was filled with undefined values. I changed calculateMaxValue to be asynchronous after which it ended up as zero length. Sorry for forgetting to update the sample code, when I made my last comment