# Determining the last row in a range of columns that contain empty cells - Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm having trouble creating a function to find the last row with data in a specified range, in this case I have data that moves in columns `A:K` and functions that use that data in `L:Z`. I want to paste data in the first empty row in the range `A:K`. I have tried using the solution of finding the first empty row in a specific column:

```
var Avals = ss.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;
```

but that isn't a viable solution for me since we may have **empty** first values in a row, and I need it to paste in a specific range. I've tried using both `getLastRow` and `getDataRange` methods but they don't satisfy the requirements.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determining the last row in a single column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632165/determining-the-last-row-in-a-single-column)

Comment: @tripleee I changed the title to distinguish the OPs question from the one you are referring to as a duplicate. The latter has 2 restrictions: it considers only `1` column (here the OP is asking for a range of columns) and also the columns could have empty cells. The accepted answer of the duplicate question you referred to relies on the fact that the column does not have empty cells before the last row with content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Goal:

You want to find the last row of a particular **range** of columns and some of these columns could contain empty cells or even the full column could be totally empty.

### Explanation:

- Select the desired range of columns you want to identify the last row with content.
- [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) column, use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get the data of this particular column.
- [reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) the data array of the column so you can [`find`the`Index`](http://findIndex) of the first non-empty cell (starting backwards).
- Deduct this row from the maximum rows in the sheet, and it will give you the last row with content of each column in the selected range. [Push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) all these values to an array.
- The [Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) value of this array will be the last row with content of the selected range.

### Code snippet:

Iterate through the columns `A:K`, find the last row for every column and then calculate the maximum last row:

```
function findLastRow() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const data = sh.getRange("A:K").getValues();
  const mR = sh.getMaxRows();
  const indexes = [];
  data[0].forEach((_,ci)=>{
   let col = data.map(d => d[ci]);
   let first_index = col.reverse().findIndex(r=>r!='');
   if(first_index!=-1){
      let max_row = mR - first_index;
      indexes.push(max_row);
   }
  });
  last_row = indexes.length > 0 ? Math.max(...indexes) : 0;
  console.log(last_row);
}
```

Then you can start pasting from `last_row+1`.

**Example Sheet for code snippet:**

Let's say we want to find the last row in the range `A:K` for which some columns might contain empty values, and there is another column that has the last row with content in the sheet. In the example sheet below, the correct answer should be `27`.

[image]

**Advantages:**

Unlike [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632165/determining-the-last-row-in-a-single-column), the solution works:

- even if any of the columns in the range contains empty values (or the full column is empty).
- for both single columns or range of columns.

**Disadvantages:**

It could potentially be slow for a large number of columns. Albeit, the number of `GAS` API calls are at the minimum possible level, there are many `JavaScript` function calls that are being used iteratively.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much! This is almost the perfect solution that I need, the only issue with this is that if all the rows are empty, as would be for the first time that data is moved, it still defaults to the last row in the sheet.

Comment: @David- Sorry for the incovenience, check my answer again! :)

Comment: No worries at all & better yet thank you for helping! With this script however now the last_row is logged as '-Infinity' so it's throwing errors when I implement it in the script :c

Comment: According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42719786/why-math-max-is-equal-to-infinity-in-es2015) `max` produces infinity when you are not passing any data in it. Meaning that, if you used my code, you have given a selection of range which has empty rows.

Comment: The destination sheet is empty, in order to help replicate the problem I believe it best to share some code. I'm attaching what I have now to the initial question!

Comment: @David- use my updated answer. You are not supposed to include the answer in the question. This could be confusing to future readers. They will see the same code in the question as well as in the answer itself. I updated the code to catch cases where the desired range of columns consist of only empty columns.