# Google Sheets - Find last column with data in array

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to find the last column in a range, but the problem is I can't specify the script to only check within an array instead of the entire sheet. I was able to use this bit of code to find the last row but I'm having trouble understanding how this can be changed to find the column instead of row.

```
function findLastRow() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const data = sh.getRange("A:K").getValues();
  const mR = sh.getMaxRows();
  const indexes = [];
  data[0].forEach((_,ci)=>{
   let col = data.map(d => d[ci]);
   let first_index = col.reverse().findIndex(r=>r!='');
   if(first_index!=-1){
      let max_row = mR - first_index;
      indexes.push(max_row);
   }
  });
  last_row = indexes.length > 0 ? Math.max(...indexes) : 0;
  console.log(last_row);
}
```

[Source for this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65776488/determining-the-last-row-in-a-range-of-columns-that-contain-empty-cells-google)

Can anyone explain to me how this function could be changed up a bit to search for the column instead of the row?

Answer (score 1):

**Description**

Finding the last row or column containing data of a range can be simplified with the use of Range.getNextDataCell().

Here is a spreadsheet with sparcely populated cells.

[image]

**Code.gs**

```
function test() {
  try {
    let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Test");
    let range = sheet.getRange("A1:D10");
    let lastRow = range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow();
    console.log("lastRow = "+lastRow);
    range = sheet.getRange("A1:E5");
    lastColumn = range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.NEXT).getColumn();
    console.log("lastColumn = "+lastColumn);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**Execution log**

```
6:14:50 PM  Notice  Execution started
6:14:51 PM  Info    lastRow = 4
6:14:51 PM  Info    lastColumn = 4
6:14:51 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

**Reference**

- [Range.getNextDataCell()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getNextDataCell(Direction))

Answer (score 1):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function findLasColumn() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const range = sh.getRange("A:K");
  const offset = range.getColumn();
  const maxColumn = Math.max(...range.getDisplayValues().map(r => r.reduceRight((n, c, i) => {
    if (!n && c) n = i;
    return n
  }, null)));
  const lastColumn = maxColumn + offset;
  console.log(lastColumn);
}
```

- When this script is run, from `"A:K"`, the last column number is returned.
- If you use `"B:K"`, the last column number is returned as the valid column number.

#### Reference:

- [reduceRight()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight)

Answer (score 0):

## Alternative Approach

You can also use the ***transpose*** method to be able to get the last column in your range.

### Tweaked Script:

```
function findLastColumn() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const range = sh.getRange("C1:H18");
  const data = transpose(range).map((values,index) => values[0].length ? index+range.getColumn() : null).filter(d => d); //The 'index+range.getColumn()' part returns the number of a non-empty col
  console.log(data[data.length-1]);
}

function transpose(range){
  return range.getValues()[0].map((_, colIndex) => range.getValues().map(row => row[colIndex]));
}
```

### Sample Sheet:

> [image]

- After running the `findLastColumn()` function

> [image]

### Reference:

- [Transpose an Array in JavaScript](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/javascript/javascript-transpose-array/)
- [JavaScript Array map()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65776488/determining-the-last-row-in-a-range-of-columns-that-contain-empty-cells-google), and `I want to paste data in the first empty row in the range A:K.` Here is a simple solution for finding the first blank row and column.

```
const data = sh.getRange(`A:K`).getDisplayValues()

const firstBlankRow = data.findIndex(row => row.every(cell => cell === ``))+1
const firstBlankCol = data[0].map((_, index) => data.flatMap(i => i[index]))
                             .findIndex(col => col.every(cell => cell === ``))+1
```

Answer (score 0):

### You can prototype a function as follows

```
Object.prototype.getLastDataColumn = function(row) {
  var lastCol = this.getLastColumn();
  if (row==null){row=1}
  var range = this.getRange(row,lastCol);
  if (range.getValue() !== "") {
    return lastCol;
  } else {
    return range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.PREVIOUS).getColumn();
  }              
}
```

and

```
Object.prototype.getLastDataRow = function(col){ // col in letter
  var lastRow = this.getLastRow();
  if (col == null){col='A'}
  var range = this.getRange(col + lastRow);
  if (range.getValue() !== "") {
    return lastRow;
  } else {
    return range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).getRow();
  }  
}
```

and then use as

```
const lastRow = sheet.getLastDataRow('B') // for column B, can be omitted
```

and

```
const lastCol = sheet.getLastDataColumn(5) // for row#5 can be omitted
```