Sort and Filter Multiple Sheets with Different Number of Columns
We have four branches, each with a fleet of vehicles. A large pool of drivers is trained to become competent in driving each vehicle. We have a spreadsheet with four sheets, one for each branch. Vehicle types differ from branch to branch, so each sheet may have a different number of columns.
Please see an example of the spreadsheet - Example Spreadsheet.

Column A has a static list of numbers ranging from 1 to 2000.
Columns B, C, and D are populated by an Array Formula matching the Employee ID to the number in column A. The Array Formula will only match the Employee ID for current employees, so there may be quite a number of unpopulated rows from column B onward. The ArrayFormula is =ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(vlookup(A3:A,IMPORTRANGE("SpeadsheetID","'SheetName'!A4:F"),{6,2, 5},false),""))
Columns E onwards have checkboxes that are checked once a driver is competent in driving a particular vehicle.

I have created a script with an onOpen trigger for one sheet, the North Branch, but ideally, I would like it to work simultaneously for all four branches.


function OnOpenTauranga() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("North");//change sheet name as required
  const sr = 4;//data startrow;
  const vs = sh.getRange(sr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1, 12).getValues();
  var sRange = sh.getRange("A4:L");
  sh.unhideRow(sRange);
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    if (r[1]==='East'||r[1]==='West'||r[1]==='South'||r[1]==='') {
      sh.getRange(i + sr, 5).setValue("FALSE");
      sh.getRange(i + sr, 6).setValue("FALSE");
      sh.getRange(i + sr, 7).setValue("FALSE");
      sh.getRange(i + sr, 8).setValue("FALSE");
      sh.getRange(i + sr, 9).setValue("FALSE");
      sh.getRange(i + sr, 10).setValue("FALSE");
      sh.getRange(i + sr, 11).setValue("FALSE");
      sh.getRange(i + sr, 12).setValue("FALSE");
      sh.hideRows(i + sr)
        }
    });
      sRange.sort({column: 3, ascending: true});
}



This:

unhides/shows all rows
sets the values in the checkboxes in column E onwards to 'FALSE' when there are empty cells in column B.
sets the values in the checkboxes in column E onwards to 'FALSE' for any
employee working for one of the other three branches, again from
column B.
shows rows from the North branch only.
sorts the North branch by column C, the Employee Name.


My script works for one sheet (Branch) but is incredibly slow. I am also not sure how to modify the script to work on Open for all four branches, given that each sheet has a different number of columns.
I would appreciate the help.
type here


You can do the loop like this:  vs.forEach((r, i) => {     if (r[1]==='East'||r[1]==='West'||r[1]==='South'||r[1]==='') {       sh.getRange(i + sr, 5,1,8).setValue("FALSE");       sh.hideRows(i + sr)         }     });

Use Spreadsheet.getSheets(), Sheet.getDataRange(), Array.forEach(), Array.map(), String().match() and Range.setValues(), like this:
/**
* Simple trigger that runs each time the user opens
* the spreadsheet.
*
* @param {Object} e The onOpen() event object.
*/
function onOpen(e) {
  if (!e) throw new Error('Please do not run the onOpen(e) function in the script editor window.');
  resetSheets_(e);
}


/**
* Resets sheets by clearing checkboxes, hiding rows, and sorting.
*
* @param {Object} e The onOpen() event object.
*/
function resetSheets_(e) {
  // version 1.1, written by --Hyde, 24 May 2024
  //  - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/78505179/13045193
  try {
    e.source.toast('Resetting tabs...');
    const sheetsToReset = /^(North|East|South|West)$/i;
    const numHeaderRows = 3;
    const sortColumnIndex = 3; // one-indexed
    const keyColumnIndex = 1; // zero-indexed
    const columnStart = 4; // zero-indexed
    let numResetted = 0;
    e.source.getSheets().forEach(sheet => {
      const sheetName = sheet.getName();
      if (!sheetName.match(sheetsToReset)) return;
      const dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
      const values = dataRange.getValues().slice(numHeaderRows);
      const keys = values.map(row => String(row[keyColumnIndex]));
      const oldCheckboxes = values.map(row => row.slice(columnStart));
      const rowsToHide = [];
      const newCheckboxes = oldCheckboxes.map((row, rowIndex) => {
        const key = keys[rowIndex];
        if (key === sheetName || (key && !key.match(sheetsToReset))) return row;
        rowsToHide.push(numHeaderRows + 1 + rowIndex);
        return row.map(_ => null);
      });
      dataRange.offset(numHeaderRows, columnStart, newCheckboxes.length, newCheckboxes[0].length).setValues(newCheckboxes);
      sheet.unhideRow(dataRange);
      hideRowsFast_(sheet, rowsToHide);
      sheet.setFrozenRows(numHeaderRows);
      sheet.sort(sortColumnIndex);
      numResetted += 1;
    })
    e.source.toast(`Done. Resetted ${numResetted} tabs.`);
  } catch (error) {
    e.source.toast(`${error.message} ${error.stack}`, 'Error in resetSheets_()', 30);
    throw error;
  }
}


/**
* Hides rows fast by grouping them before hiding.
*
* @param {SpreadsheetApp.Sheet} sheet The sheet where to hide rows.
* @param {Number[]} rowsToHide The 1-indexed row numbers of rows to hide.
*/
function hideRowsFast_(sheet, rowsToHide) {
  // version 1.3, written by --Hyde, 16 August 2023
  //  - see https://support.google.com/docs/thread/230514216?msgid=230523321
  rowsToHide
    .sort((a, b) => a - b)
    .reduce((result, value, index, numbers) => {
      if (!index || value !== 1 + numbers[index - 1]) result.push([value]);
      const lastIndex = result.length - 1;
      result[lastIndex][1] = (result[lastIndex][1] || 0) + 1;
      return result;
    }, [])
    .forEach(group => sheet.hideRows(group[0], group[1]));
}

See
Spreadsheet.getSheets(),
Sheet.getDataRange(),
Array.forEach(),
Array.map(),
String.match() and
Range.setValues().
The formula used to fill column B outputs many zero-length text strings, which causes the spreadsheet's data range get extended all the way to the bottom, which slows things down considerably. To output tryly blank values instead, remove the ,"" bit, like this:
=arrayformula(ifna(vlookup( 
  A3:A, importrange("...id...", "SheetName!A4:F"), { 6, 2, 5 }, false 
)))


It keeps timing out after 30 seconds

Simple triggers are limited to 30 seconds of runtime. That is enough in the sample spreadsheet you shared. To get more runtime, remove onOpen(e), rename resetSheets_(e) to resetSheets(e) and create an installable trigger to run it.

I have over 2000 rows in each sheet. I ran it again, and it took over 30 minutes before timing out. It needs to run on open because of the arrayformula importrange formula in column B. The source importrange spreadsheet changes daily. This formula therefore populates or depopulates hidden rows.

The code can be optimized by processing all rows in one go. However, if column B changes so that branches are no longer in the same order, doesn't that expose you to the risk of rows getting misaligned? Please edit the question and show the "arrayformula importrange" formula.

The formula has been added to the question

I amended the formula and closed and reopened the spreadsheet. Every cell B3:D states "ERROR Loading Data"

I went back to it, and the error had cleared. I closed and opened it again, and it timed out after 1800 seconds halfway through the last sheet.

Edited the answer to show how to do this much faster with Range.setValues() and my hideRowsFast_() utility function.

That works perfectly - thank you. It took 7 seconds to complete.

The following code is my attempt to separate the logic of your program in separate code blocks and make it easier to understand it.
I can't say for sure if it will match your requirements, but, it might give you some clue about how you can improve your code for achieve your requirements.
Here is the code - N.B.make sure that before testing it, make a copy of your data:
/*
onOpen function.
*/
function onOpen(e) {
  start_spreadsheet();
}

/**
 * Main function of this spreadsheet. It's intended to be executed on the "onOpen(e)" function.
 * @customfunction
 */
function start_spreadsheet() {
  try {

    /** Spreadsheet to work with. */
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

    /** All sheets from the spreadsheet. */
    var sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();

    /** Temporal variable to store the sheet to work. */
    var temp_sheet = null;

    // Loop the sheets obtained and work only with the mentioned ones in the question: 
    for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {

      // Set the sheet to the temporal variable: 
      temp_sheet = sheets[i];

      // Apply the following logic on certain sheets only:
      switch (temp_sheet.getName()) {
        case "North":
        case "East":
        case "South":
        case "West":

          /** Number of rows to loop to work with (i.e employees). 
           * NOTE: The (-3) is for exclude the first 3 rows: (Driver's Competence Register - <SHEET_NAME> & ID). */
          var rows_to_loop = temp_sheet.getRange("A4:A" + temp_sheet.getLastRow()).getNumRows() - 3;

          /** Index of the row to loop and check if it's empty. */
          var incr_row = 4;

          /** Number of columns the sheet has - substracting the first 4 columns: (ID, Branch, Employee & Employee Type).
           * Modified from https://stackoverflow.com/a/72209117/12511801 */
          var num_of_columns = temp_sheet.getRange("3:3").getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.NEXT).getColumn() - 4;

          /** The name of the employee to check if he/she is working in another branch. */
          var employee_name = "";
          temp_sheet.getRange("C" + incr_row).getValue();

          /** The name of the branch where the employee is working. */
          var employee_branch = "";
          temp_sheet.getRange("B" + incr_row).getValue();

          /** Get all employees and branches - in order to check any employee working for one of the other three branches.
           * The data is sorted for further search. The idea is to loop this 2D array and then check if the employee is 
           * duplicated in another branch(es).
           */
          var all_employees_and_branches = temp_sheet.getRange("B4:C" + rows_to_loop).getValues().sort();

          /** Flag/boolean to check if the employee is working in another branch. */
          var is_employee_working_elsewhere = false;

          // Sets the values in the checkboxes in column E onwards to 'FALSE' when there are empty cells in column B.
          for (var j = 0; j < rows_to_loop; j++) {

            employee_name = temp_sheet.getRange("C" + incr_row).getValue();
            employee_branch = temp_sheet.getRange("B" + incr_row).getValue();

            // Sets the values in the checkboxes in column E onwards to 'FALSE' for any employee working for one of the other three branches, again from column B.
            is_employee_working_elsewhere = check_employee_criteria(all_employees_and_branches, employee_name, employee_branch);

            if (temp_sheet.getRange("B" + incr_row).toString().trim() == "" || (is_employee_working_elsewhere)) {
              temp_sheet.getRange(incr_row, 5, 1, num_of_columns).setValues("FALSE");
            }
            incr_row++;
          }

          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    }

  } catch (err) {
    Logger.log("Error at processing the spreadsheet: " + err.message);
    Logger.log(err.stack);
  }
}

/**
 * Function that returns a boolean indicating if the employee is working in other 
 * branch(es) "different to the supplied in the parameters"
 * @param {Array} data The data (i.e. employees and branches) - already sorted.
 * @param {String} employee The name of the employee.
 * @param {Array} branch The name of the branch of the employee.
 * {returns} TRUE (if the employee is working on other branch(es)).
 * @customfunction
 */
function check_employee_criteria(data, employee, branch) {
  /** Boolean to return with the result of the process. */
  var flag = false;

  /** The branch-employee data pair. */
  var record = undefined;

  /** Name of the employee found in the data. */
  var name_empl = "";

  /** Name of the branch found in the data. */
  var branch_empl = "";

  try {

    // Loop the data: 
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

      // Get the name of the employee and the branch from the data: 
      record = data[i];
      name_empl = record[1];
      branch_empl = record[0];

      // If the employee is found working in other branch(es), the condition is met.
      if (name_empl == employee && branch_empl != branch) {
        flag = true;
        break;
      }
    }
  } catch (err) {
    Logger.log("Error at validating if the employee is working in another branch(es): " + err.message);
    Logger.log(err.stack);
  }
  return flag;
}

